# two degree of freedom

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm Angelo.
How I can do a joint with two degree of freedom?
If I do two time the joint, a first time for first degree of freedom, and a second time for second degree of freedom, with axis xyz="1 0 0" and xyz="0 1 0" respectively,and if i try to set any value on rpy in the first and second joint I see with rviz only the effect of the last join.
thank you very mich
Angelo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27863/two-degree-of-freedom/) by [manang](https://answers.ros.org/users/1809/manang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-28**:
What? This question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am assuming you mean in URDF. If so continue reading! I had the exact same problem with a hip joint the other day.

In order to get two degrees of freedom, make TWO *revolute* joints in the same location connected via a dummy link.

Example in Pseudo XML:

```
link thigh_link
link leg_link

link placeholder
 origin="0 0 0" //NOTE: this link has no change in location nor any geometry

joint hip_joint_x type="revolute"
 parent = "thigh_link"
 child = "placeholder"
 axis xyz="1 0 0"
/joint

joint hip_joint_y type="revolute"
 parent = "placeholder"
 child = "leg_link"
 axis xyz="0 1 0"
/joint
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [TabStock](https://answers.ros.org/users/5367/tabstock/) with karma: 61 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3